# Is Sigma AF 70-300 f/4.0-5.6 DG APO Macro compatible with Nikon D5100?

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d5100, sigma

Is the **Sigma AF 70-300 f/4.0-5.6 DG APO Macro** compatible with the Nikon D5100 camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. This lens is made for Canon, Pentax, Sigma, Sony/Minolta, and Nikon mounts. You would need the Nikon version — F-mount. However, do also note that it won't autofocus on your camera, as the D5100 does not have the focus motor necessary to drive it.

Comment: Thanks, I meant the lens for the Nikon camera. I was only not sure about the specific model.